# InnoSetup: Pascal script for cancelling setup when file/folder exists

Tags: installation, inno-setup

In my InnoSetup I use several file actions in the InstallRun section. If those are executed correctly without problems then a certain temp folder should have been deleted.

If something has gone wrong then the temp folder is still there. In that case I want the setup to be canceled with a messagebox displaying an error message of my choice.

As I have no experience (yet) with Pascal script I kindly ask you to provide me with an example script yo do this.

Thanks in advance!

Addition:
I'll now explain the reason I need this. The scenario is updating an existing version, which is a Windows Service application. Before updating those files I have to uninstall the services first. For this I use my own commandline that's in the installation package. The other new files will be temporary unpacked to a temp folder (subfolder of app folder). After the Windows services are uninstalled the new files are moved from the temp folder to the app folder. If something goes wrong here I want to cancel the setup and show an error message to the user. I can best tell if something has gone wrong by checking if the temp folder is still there.

Comment: What is `InstallRun` section ?

Comment: What sort of things do you run? Does it rely on the application that's just been installed or is it a prerequisite? An easier (and much better) option would be to extract and run the files in the `PrepareToInstall()` event function. If you can answer my points, I can do a fully answer.

Comment: @Deanna: I have updated my question with why I need this. If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean the `[Run]` section, it is not possible to cancel the installation that late in the process.

Instead, you should look at using `PrepareToInstall`.  In this, all you need to do is to stop and deregister the old service, either directly via API or by invoking a command on the old service EXE as you choose.  (Don't forget to handle the case when the service doesn't exist yet, for new installs.)

After this `[Files]` will replace the files as normal and you can then `[Run]` or use code (via `AfterInstall` or `CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)`, depending on the time you want it to happen) to re-register and start the service.

No need to muck around with temporary folders -- which is good, because that would have caused problems for uninstall as well.

Comment: The procedure to de-install the current running Windows Services involves more than a standard de-install, so I need to use a custom build command-line EXE for that, which is in the setup package.

Comment: And as I said, I usually compile that sort of functionality into the service executable itself.  Then I can just run it (from PrepareToInstall, as previously noted) with a parameter like "-stop -uninstall" to stop and remove itself.  Or you can [call the APIs directly](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Service_-_Functions_to_Start%2C_Stop%2C_Install%2C_Remove_a_Service) if you prefer.